# how to use `.ForSingletonOf<>` in StructureMap

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

Why when I use `.ForSingletonOf<T>()` the result of messagebox is `false`

```
public static class IoC
{
    public static void InitIoC()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Configure(config =>
        {
            config.ForSingletonOf<IDependency>().Use<ConcreteDepenedency>();
        });
    }
}
```

MessageBox:

```
var instance1 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ConcreteDepenedency>();
var instance2 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ConcreteDepenedency>();

MessageBox.Show(instance1.Equals(instance2).ToString());
```

I don't want each time I call `ObjectFactory.GetInstance` it creates a new instance.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `Object.ReferenceEquals`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad no there is no different..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering the `IDependency` type as a singleton, but when you are resolving (via `GetInstance`), you are resolving `ConcreteDepenedency`.

You have two options to fix this:

Option #1: Register `ConcreteDepenedency` as singleton like this:

```
config.ForSingletonOf<ConcreteDepenedency>().Use<ConcreteDepenedency>();
```

Option #2: When you resolve, resolve `IDependency` like this:

```
var instance1 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IDependency>();
var instance2 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IDependency>();
```

By the way, if you want to test if two variables are referring to the same object, use the [Object.ReferenceEquals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: How should I get the instance? What is your suggestion?

Comment: I gave you two options. If you want to keep the registration as is, then use Option #2.